# Liferay encryption algorithm implementation in .Net c#

Tags: c#, liferay, pbkdf2

I am trying to write the same algorithm in c# of what Liferay uses PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1/160/128000 as we have hashed passwords migrated to different platforms. however the hashed passwords values are coming as different in C#
Not too sure where I am doing wrong. I am not very much familiar with Java.

parameters passed in Java are

```
String algorithm = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1/160/128000"
String plainTextPassword = "!!Fres1966"
String encryptedPassword = null
```

hash value in Java = "AAAAoAAB9ACnaq7ogwbkgRWfNcsfFh2DEMKmfl7JAqR8SAqk"
hash value in c# = "FAAAAAD0AQAAAAAAAAAAAFJZUX3EUFdhFHeMZLSdlo9RxsxO"

There is one line of code which I have not been able to replicate is

```
BigEndianCodec.putLong(_saltBytes, 0, SecureRandomUtil.nextLong())
```

not too sure what this line of code is doing and how can I replicate the similar logic in c#

Code in Java-------------

```
public class PBKDF2PasswordEncryptor
extends BasePasswordEncryptor implements PasswordEncryptor {

@Override
public String[] getSupportedAlgorithmTypes() {
    return new String[] {PasswordEncryptorUtil.TYPE_PBKDF2};
}

@Override
protected String doEncrypt(
        String algorithm, String plainTextPassword,
        String encryptedPassword)
    throws PwdEncryptorException {

    try {
        PBKDF2EncryptionConfiguration pbkdf2EncryptionConfiguration =
            new PBKDF2EncryptionConfiguration();

        pbkdf2EncryptionConfiguration.configure(
            algorithm, encryptedPassword);

        byte[] saltBytes = pbkdf2EncryptionConfiguration.getSaltBytes();

        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(
            plainTextPassword.toCharArray(), saltBytes,
            pbkdf2EncryptionConfiguration.getRounds(),
            pbkdf2EncryptionConfiguration.getKeySize());

        String algorithmName = algorithm;

        int index = algorithm.indexOf(CharPool.SLASH);

        if (index > -1) {
            algorithmName = algorithm.substring(0, index);
        }

        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(
            algorithmName);

        SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

        byte[] secretKeyBytes = secretKey.getEncoded();

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(
            2 * 4 + saltBytes.length + secretKeyBytes.length);

        byteBuffer.putInt(pbkdf2EncryptionConfiguration.getKeySize());
        byteBuffer.putInt(pbkdf2EncryptionConfiguration.getRounds());
        byteBuffer.put(saltBytes);
        byteBuffer.put(secretKeyBytes);

        return Base64.encode(byteBuffer.array());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new PwdEncryptorException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

private static final int _KEY_SIZE = 160;

private static final int _ROUNDS = 128000;

private static final int _SALT_BYTES_LENGTH = 8;

private static Pattern _pattern = Pattern.compile(
    "^.*/?([0-9]+)?/([0-9]+)$");

private class PBKDF2EncryptionConfiguration {

    public void configure(String algorithm, String encryptedPassword)
        throws PwdEncryptorException {

        if (Validator.isNull(encryptedPassword)) {
            Matcher matcher = _pattern.matcher(algorithm);

            if (matcher.matches()) {
                _keySize = GetterUtil.getInteger(
                    matcher.group(1), _KEY_SIZE);

                _rounds = GetterUtil.getInteger(matcher.group(2), _ROUNDS);
            }

            BigEndianCodec.putLong(
                _saltBytes, 0, SecureRandomUtil.nextLong());
        }   
        else {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[16];

            try {
                byte[] encryptedPasswordBytes = Base64.decode(
                    encryptedPassword);

                System.arraycopy(
                    encryptedPasswordBytes, 0, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                throw new PwdEncryptorException(
                    "Unable to extract salt from encrypted password " +
                        e.getMessage(),
                    e);
            }

            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);

            _keySize = byteBuffer.getInt();
            _rounds = byteBuffer.getInt();

            byteBuffer.get(_saltBytes);
        }
    }

    public int getKeySize() {
        return _keySize;
    }

    public int getRounds() {
        return _rounds;
    }

    public byte[] getSaltBytes() {
        return _saltBytes;
    }

    private int _keySize = _KEY_SIZE;
    private int _rounds = _ROUNDS;
    private byte[] _saltBytes = new byte[_SALT_BYTES_LENGTH];

}
```

}

### Code in c#

```
public string HasPassword(string password)
{
 byte[] salt = new byte[8];    
 Rfc2898DeriveBytes Rfcbytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt,
             128000);
         byte[] key = Rfcbytes.GetBytes(160/8);

        var ms = new MemoryStream(8+salt.Length+key.Length);
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(ms))
        {
            writer.Write(160/8);   
            writer.Write(128000);
            writer.Write(salt);
            writer.Write(key);
        }   
        byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
        string finalhash = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

 return finalhash;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BigEndianCodec.putLong(_saltBytes, 0, SecureRandomUtil.nextLong())`  Seems to be "Generate a random 8-byte value and write it into an array (in Big Endian order; but it's random, so that doesn't matter)".

So you'd want

```
using (RandomNumberGenerator csprng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
{
    csprng.GetBytes(salt);
}
```

Between allocating `salt` and passing it to `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`' ctor.

Comment: Thanks for the response, managed to crack it finally. Salt was stored in the hash itself, once we extracted the correct salt then was able to get the right hash.