# Java to C# Conversion - base64 byte array pbkdf2EncryptionConfiguration

Tags: java, c#, arrays, byte, pbkdf2

Essentially moving data from a java based system to a C# one.

Code from the java side does the following to the password

---------- code -------

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( 2 * 4 + saltBytes.length + secretKeyBytes.length);

byteBuffer.putInt(pbkdf2EncryptionConfiguration.getKeySize());
byteBuffer.putInt(pbkdf2EncryptionConfiguration.getRounds());
byteBuffer.put(saltBytes);
byteBuffer.put(secretKeyBytes);

return Base64.encode(byteBuffer.array());
```

---------- end code -------

In summary, a byte array that starts with a number, has another number, followed by the salt, followed by the secretKey

My issue is, java bytes are different than C# (signed/unsigned) and I essentially just want to extract the salt/secret key.

My process so far in C# is to

---------- code -------

```
byte[] actualPasswordByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(hash);

int abc = BitConverter.ToInt32(items, 0);
int def = BitConverter.ToInt32(items, 4);

byte[] salt = new byte[SaltByteSize];
byte[] key = new byte[HashByteSize];

using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, 8, 128000))
{
    salt = deriveBytes.Salt;
    key = deriveBytes.GetBytes(leftOverBytes);
}
```

---------- end code -------

But I'm not getting the right values

Comment: Is [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42210667/liferay-encrytion-algoritham-implementaion-in-net-c-sharp) relevant or useful?

Answer (score 0):

- `def` holds the number of rounds, but you hard-coded it to 128000.
- You should be reading the salt from your stream and passing it as input to `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, but you told the class to generate an 8 byte random salt.

Since you're letting the salt get randomly generated, you now have code that takes ~100ms to produce a random answer which could have been produced in ~10ns.

Every value in the byte stream you're (mostly-not-)reading is important.  If you find that you've hard-coded any values you've done something wrong.

Comment: That was only meant to be a representation of pseduo-code.